# JMeter replace HTTP method or protocol

Tags: replace, jmeter

I want to replace all/most of HTTP Request's method or protocol

I tried to use Search option in JMeter (also in latest nightly) and I'm finding the http protocol or CONNECT method but when clicking replace none of the occurrences have changed

How can I replace it in JMeter script? only using notepad search&replace?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible except in texteditor.

It is partly intentional as search/replace feature in JMeter is built for correlation / variabilization than for pure replacement.

Still if you feel it should be possible, propose a patch after discussion on dev mailing list.